# How to open/close a snazzy-info-window programmatically in angular-google-maps?

Tags: angular, google-maps, infowindow, angular-google-maps

If I am using `agm-info-window`, you can call open/close programmatically from the controller

Template:

```
<agm-data-layer [geoJson]="geoJsonObject"  [style]="styleFunc" (layerClick)="clicked($event, gm, infoWindow)" >
    <agm-info-window [disableAutoPan]="true" 
                     [latitude]="infoWindowLat" 
                     [longitude] = "infoWindowLong" 
                     [isOpen]="infoWindowIsOpen"]
                      #infoWindow>
      {{infoWindowText}}
   </agm-info-window>
  </agm-data-layer>
```

Controller:

```
clicked(clickEvent, gm, infoWindow) {

 if (gm.lastOpen != null) 
 {
   gm.lastOpen.close();
 }

 gm.lastOpen = infoWindow;
 infoWindow.open();
```

}

But if I use `<agm-snazzy-info-window>`, `open()` and `close()` are undefined.

```
<agm-snazzy-info-window [isOpen]="infoWindowIsOpen" 
                          [latitude]="infoWindowLat" 
                          [longitude]="infoWindowLong"
                          [closeWhenOthersOpen]="true" 
                          [closeOnMapClick]="true"  
                          [showCloseButton]="false"  
                          [openOnMarkerClick]="true"
                          ([backgroundColor]="'#FFF'"  
                          #infoWindow>
      <ng-template>
        {{infoWindowText}}
      </ng-template>
  </agm-snazzy-info-window>
```

How can I open/ close a `<agm-snazzy-info-window>` from the controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed use the isOpen attribute to dynamically open/close the Snazzy info window.

```
/* component.ts */    
      isSnazzyInfoWindowOpened: boolean = false;

      constructor(@Inject(ChangeDetectorRef) private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
      }

      toggleSnazzyInfoWindow() {
        this.isSnazzyInfoWindowOpened = !this.isSnazzyInfoWindowOpened;
      }

      /**
       * You can omit this function if closeWhenOthersOpen and closeOnMapClick are false
       */
      snazzyInfoWindowIsToggled($isOpen: boolean) {
        console.log(`snazzyInfoWindowIsToggled ${$isOpen}`);
        // Keep isSnazzyInfoWindowOpened up-to-date (e.g. if window was closed on map click)
        this.isSnazzyInfoWindowOpened = $isOpen;
        // Force detect changes.
        // Not necessarily needed. Depends on your projet
        // Here needed if window was closed on map click
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      }
```

Template:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="50.523458" [longitude]="2.800024">
        <agm-snazzy-info-window #snazzyInfoWindow
    [closeWhenOthersOpen]="true"
         [closeOnMapClick]="true" 
     [isOpen]="isSnazzyInfoWindowOpened" 
     (isOpenChange)="snazzyInfoWindowIsToggled($event)"
     [latitude]="50.523458" [longitude]="2.800024">
            <ng-template>
                    Hello!          
            </ng-template>
        </agm-snazzy-info-window>
</agm-map>
<button (click)="toggleSnazzyInfoWindow()">Toggle SnazzyInfoWindow</button>
```

Here is a working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1z39nb

Answer (score 1):

When you use infoWindow.open() not work in agm/snazzy-in-window just try this

```
<agm-map>
  <agm-marker 
    (mouseOver)="onMouseOver(infoWindow, $event)" 
    (mouseOut)="onMouseOut(infoWindow, $event)">

    <agm-snazzy-info-window 
      [closeWhenOthersOpen]="true"
      [panOnOpen]="false"
      [placement]="'bottom'" #infoWindow>

      <ng-template>
        <h6 class="mb-0">this is marker</h6>
      </ng-template>

    </agm-snazzy-info-window>

  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

component.ts

```
onMouseOver(infoWindow, $event: MouseEvent) {
  infoWindow._openInfoWindow();
}

onMouseOut(infoWindow, $event: MouseEvent) {
  infoWindow._closeInfoWindow();
}
```